# Cannot cross-compile if I import "C"

Tags: linux, windows, go, cross-compiling, goracle

## Environment

- Windows 10
- Go 1.13.7

```bsh
GOOS=windows
GOARCH=amd64
CGO_ENABLED=1
```

## The problem

After days of trying to cross-compile my project, I figured that if one of my files does import "C", it seems that `go build` just skip it.

Here is my first file `first.go`:

```golang
package main

import "C"

type myFirstType struct {
    str string
}

func main() {
    v := myFirstType{str: "Hello"}
    printFirstTypeWithParam(v)
}
```

And here is the second `second.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func printFirstTypeWithParam(v myFirstType) {
    fmt.Println(v.str)
}
```

When I run `go build`, all is correct.
But when I run `env GOOS=linux go build`, here is the output:

```bsh
# test-package
.\second.go:7:32: undefined: myFirstType
```

As soon as I remove the `import "C"` line, all work perfectly.

## Why is this a problem ?

In the real project, I use **gopkg.in/goracle.v2**, and this library does use C libraries in `drv.go`:

```golang
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./odpi/include -I./odpi/src -I./odpi/embed

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dpi.c"
*/
import "C"
```

When I run the same build command on my project (`env GOOS=linux go build`), here is the output:

```bsh
# myproject/vendor/gopkg.in/goracle.v2
vendor\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\drv_10.go:22:2: undefined: ConnectionParams
vendor\gopkg.in\goracle.v2\drv_10.go:23:2: undefined: drv
```

Both undefined type and variable are defined in this `drv.go` file.

Is this normal behavior, or am I missing something ?

Comment: this is normal behaviour, go by default gets the c files needed for your os when downloading a library

Comment: Is there no way to download c files needed for the OS in GOOS ?

Comment: not that i know of, manually getting the files may work. i personally use vm's when cross compiling is not an option

Comment: Go downloads whatever is in the repository. C source files do not specify what OS they are for, so Go would have no way to exclude them on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

goracle was moved to [godror](https://github.com/godror/godror) and doesn't support cross-compile. Read the same issue here: https://github.com/go-goracle/goracle/issues/171